# Eclipse and git "Use the new project Wizard" extremely confusing

Tags: eclipse

I have managed to use egit to clone one of my C++ github projects. When I get to the end there is a message which says "Select a wizard to use for importing projects". If I select "use the new project wizard" then I can't see any of my data - I get a project with some includes and that's it. I'm struggling to understand why this option exists? Do I have to import as a "general project". I'm not too familiar with eclipse and I find this very confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes remote repository is empty and all you want is to create a new poroject start developing and then push your code.
If your remote repository allready have code in it just Fetch first then add code and finally push.

Comment: If I use the "New project wizard" the project seems to be under no version control - it's as though I didn't import a project at all. So I can't Fetch the code.

Comment: You are right you still have to make share porject this way. It is very confusing option, anyway i allways just use import as general project.